# In Node.JS, how would I "shift" up an entire range of values with the Google Sheets API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet which is read & written from by a Node.JS app.

In one scenario, I need to shift an entire range up (move `A3:D` up by one), but as I am extremely new to the Google Sheets API, I have failed to do so. I have thought about using these methods:

## a) Copy all values in a range and paste it up by one

Using `sheets.spreadsheet.values.get`, I would get all the values in `A3:D` then save it as an array using `toLocaleString()`. Then, I would clear all the values in that range. Finally, I will put that data in a range `A2:D`.

**Problem:** When setting the data, would I use an array or would I simply use `response.value.data` or even simply `response.value`? How would I pass my array to `sheets.spreadsheet.values.set` as a parameter?

## b) Insert a row below all the values

I would use the method found in this post: [Shift Cell Range in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284258/shift-cell-range-in-google-sheets)

**Problem:** This seems like a good method, but I have a feeling it will cause strange behaviour. I have a 'title' row in my spreadsheet (with no actual data) and I am worried that doing this will override that. Additionally, what is the best method to get the row number where I would actually insert the new row?

I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

## EDIT 1

I have managed to scrape together this code. I am trying to make a [CutPasteRequst](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#CutPasteRequest), but I cannot figure out the syntax and how I would make this work.

```js
var spreadsheetId = 'My sheet ID';

sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
    auth: client, // 'client' is already authorised
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,

    requestBody: {
        source: 'Words to display!A3:D',
        destination: 'Words to display!A2',
        pasteType: 'pasteValues.PASTE_VALUES'
    }
},
function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('API error: ' + err);
    }
});
```

API errors:

2019-09-18T05:33:03.209240+00:00 app[web.1]: The API returned an error: Error:

```
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "source": Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "destination": Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "paste_type": Cannot find field.
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet by including the input and output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Here is what I need it to do: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tJlBZGTF3K8cg8kaO4CEGrXFD6R00aDACoF6q9opKkM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your Spreadsheet, I thought that the Spreadsheet is different from your question. So I'm confusing. Can I ask you about your current question? If you want to change the question, please update it.

Comment: I don't see how my question doesn't reflect the spreadsheet. Please assume the output I am looking for is what's displayed in the sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the row 1 in the sheet of "Before" is deleted. You want to delete the row 1 of "Before". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I wanted to shift A3:D up one such that it overrides A2:D2 but not A1:D1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to propose a sample script, can you provide your current script? By this, I can confirm about the current situation of your script. If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: Please check the edited post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed 2 sample scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and those were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following situation using googleapis with Node.js.

  - From

    ```
    1   Alpha   Beta    Gamma   Delta
    2   a1      b1      c1      d1
    3   a2      b2      c2      d2
    4   a3      b3      c3      d3
    5   a4      b4      c4      d4
    6   a5      b5      c5      d5
    ```
  - From

    ```
    1   Alpha   Beta    Gamma   Delta
    2   a2      b2      c2      d2
    3   a3      b3      c3      d3
    4   a4      b4      c4      d4
    5   a5      b5      c5      d5
    ```
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script.

### Patten 1:

In this pattern, the cutPaste request with the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate is used. The values of "A3:D" are copied to "A2:D".

#### Sample script:

```
const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = ###;  // Please set sheet ID.

sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
  {
    auth: client,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          cutPaste: {
            source: {
              sheetId: sheetId,
              startRowIndex: 2,
              startColumnIndex: 0,
              endColumnIndex: 4
            },
            destination: { sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: 1 },
            pasteType: "PASTE_NORMAL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('API error: ' + err);
    }
});
```

### Patten 2:

In this pattern, the deleteDimension request with the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate is used. The row 2 is deleted.

#### Sample script:

```
const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = ###;  // Please set sheet ID.

sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
  {
    auth: client,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          deleteDimension: {
            range: {
              sheetId: sheetId,
              startIndex: 1,
              endIndex: 2,
              dimension: "ROWS"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          appendDimension: {
            sheetId: sheetId,
            dimension: "ROWS",
            length: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('API error: ' + err);
    }
});
```

- In this sample script, after one row was deleted, new row is added using the appendDimension request.

### Note:

- At the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate, please use [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange) which is not a1Notation.
- When you use this script, if an error occurs, please use the latest version of googleapis. Now the latest version is 43.0.0.

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [CutPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#cutpasterequest)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)
- [AppendDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appenddimensionrequest)

Comment: Pattern1 is the one I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @CAG2 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.